# error C2309: is not a member of CDialog

Tags: c++, mfc, header

I have structure: PrintChooseDlg.h

```
#ifndef PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
#define PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
#include <string>
#pragma once
#endif


class CPrintChooseDlg : public CDialog
{


public:
    int choosing;
    /*afx_msg void OnPrinter1();
    afx_msg void OnPrinter2();*/
CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
enum { IDD = IDD_PRINTBOX };


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    protected:
    //afx_msg void OnPrinter1();
    //afx_msg void OnPrinter2();
    virtual void OnPrinter1();
    virtual void OnPrinter2();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

and PrintChooseDlg.cpp

```
// PrintChoose.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tungsten.h"
#include "PrintChooseDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
// PrintChoose

//IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(PrintChoose, CWnd)
CPrintChooseDlg::CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CPrintChooseDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CChooseLabelDlg)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add member initialization here
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}


void CPrintChooseDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CChooseLabelDlg)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add DDX and DDV calls here
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPrintChooseDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER1,OnPrinter1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER2,OnPrinter2)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// PrintChoose message handlers

void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter1()
{
    choosing=0;
    CDialog::OnPrinter1();
}
void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter2()
{
    choosing=1;
    CDialog::OnPrinter2();
}
```

and in the main file where i am running from, i define the following headers:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tungsten.h"
#include "TungstenDlg.h"
using namespace std;
#include<sstream>
#include <string>
```

The problem is i am always getting the following errors: error C2039: 'OnPrinter1': is not a member of 'CDialog'
error C2039: 'OnPrinter2': is not a member of 'CDialog'

What i tried is to add `#include <string>` at my header and make sure that the headers are not repeated, and defining Printer1 and Pronter 2 in the main file where i am running from, but i still get the same error. I appreciate your help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The message is quite descriptive, `CDialog` has no function `OnPrinter1`, so you can't call `CDialog::OnPrinter1`.

Comment: I am a beginner in c++. Isn't virtual void OnPrinter1(); is a function inside the class?

Comment: It's a function in **CPrintChooseDlg**, not **CDialog**. As an analogy, just because a person knows how to do something, doesn't mean their parents do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the address of a member function, you need to use `&CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter1`.

Really old VC++, like VC6, didn't care about the correct syntax and generated incorrect message maps.